# List is not updated after deleting

Tags: java, android

The deleted file is still visible after deletion. Please help me.The deleted file is still visible after deletion. Please help me

MY java code:

```
   case R.id.menuDelete:
                    if (file.exists()) {
                        final android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(DocumentActivity.this);
                        builder
                                .setMessage("Delete this document folder?")
                                .setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                        for (File file1 : file.listFiles())
                                            file1.delete();
                                        file.delete();
                                        Toast.makeText(DocumentActivity.this, "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                       finish();
```

adapter:

```
public void loadData(List<DocumentModel> lstDocument) {
    if (lstDocument != null && lstDocument.size() > 0) {
        this.lstDocument.clear();
        this.lstDocument.addAll(lstDocument);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); => loadData(listFile);

Comment: how do i add this code?

Comment: please share all code java and adapter

Comment: Do you mean that it's still visible in the file browser?

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, your `adapter` has `lstDocument` list. So if you perform delete operation, you must also update `lstDocument` before `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`.

code will look like :

```
case R.id.menuDelete:
// write your file delete operation here
lstDocument.clear();
// or if you wanna remove specific item, lstDocument.remove(index);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```